# DHCPD (Slackware) - Disabling auto-generation of gateway as DNS server

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, gateway, slackware

Good day,

I am using a Linux workstation on Slackware 13.37.

One "problem" I have had to deal with ever since 11.0 is the following:

- DNS servers are queried and determined at startup by DHCP daemon (DHCPD)
- This is invoked at startup by a script located at `/etc/rc.d/rc.dhcpd`
- My DNS servers for my ISP are resolved correctly, and are stored in a list located at `/etc/resolv.conf`

However, the one annoying problem is that my gateway IP (ie: `192.168.1.1`) is always automatically put at the top of the list in `resolv.conf`, meaning I have to always wait for a timeout before a valid DNS server is used to resolve an address (ie: timeout on 192.168.1.1 because it is not actually a DNS server, then DHCP uses the next server in the list). I could lower my DNS resolution timeout so the gateway query times out quicker, but that's not what I want, as I don't want to degrade the abilities of legitimate DNS servers.

What I would like to do is change how DHCPD operates so that it does **NOT** put my gateway IP address at the beginning of this list. I've searched via "man dhcpd", etc, and haven't found the exact answer yet. Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I don't want to do this in general, as it will affect hostname resolution for machines on my LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with two DHCP daemons under Linux - `udhcpd` and `isc-dhcp-server` (this is the one you are probably using).

Both allow you to edit stanzas in their respective configuration files to hand out whatever addresses you like as DNS servers.  Try a `man dhcpd.conf` or similar for details.